# Tools for one-off processing and conversion of large data

Tags: multicore, data-processing, format-conversion

I am about to start a research project that will require a lot of data conversion and processing operations. On one hand, the data is rather massive - 10GB is typical for a raw dataset - so efficiency is an issue. On the other hand, many of these operations will be one-off, and rarely re-run, so building a deploy-able application is an overkill. It is *not* a user application, but mostly an experiment.

Some characteristics and constraints:

1. A lot of chained format conversions - JSON and XML to tabular format, then some patching, then text indexing, then exporting to some other format, etc.
2. I have a multi-core machine, but not several machines, at least to begin with.
3. Data does not fit as a whole in main memory, and from my experience, exploiting several cores is called for.

What are some recommended tools for handling such a project? My preferences are:

1. Easy-as-possible handling of multiple formats (JSON, XML, CSV)
2. Supporting multiple sources and sinks (text files, archives, databases)
3. Makes use of multiple cores
4. Little as possible administration, deployment issues, etc.

Programming language is not an issue, and I can manage Windows or Linux. Thanks!

Comment: MS DTS jumps to mind, if you have that available to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services